# Receive payments using PaymentRequest without 3rd party processors

Tags: google-chrome, payment-request-api, google-pay

Google Chrome now supports receiving payments with [`PaymentRequest API`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/payments/) using a [list of 3rd party payment processors](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/#participating-google-pay-processors).

But I cannot understand if Google supports receiving payments with Google account only, without 3rd party processors, probably with Google Pay.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote from the article you linked to (emphasis mine):

> The Payment Request API is designed to be vendor-agnostic, meaning it does not require use of a particular payment system. It's not a new payment method, nor does it integrate directly with payment processors; rather, it is a conduit from the **user's payment and shipping information** to merchants, [...]

In other words, the purpose of this API is to allow you to receive *payment information*, e.g. a payment card number or some sort of payment token. It's not an end-to-end solution for payments - just an easier and safer approach to the checkout experience.

Furthermore, the Payment Request API is an open standard - it's not tied to Google and different browsers may have different implementations. Your second link (list of 3rd party payment processors) actually refers to [Google Pay](https://developers.google.com/pay/), which is a Google product unrelated to the Payment Request API (however, Google Pay can be used as a payment method through Payment Request API on supported browsers).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So if I use Google Pay as a payment method, do I still need a merchant account of 3rd party processors? There should be an obvious answer, but unfortunately Google docs are not clear for me )

Comment: Yes - as a rule of thumb, if you're selling anything online through any means, you need a payment processor. Google Pay just makes it easier to facilitate the payment, i.e. connect your customer to your payment processor and allow them to securely transmit payment information.